# Accepting the answer given by a certain person

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, accepted-answer

I have posted a few questions on Stack Overflow. And I have accepted the answers for most of them.

Stack Overflow gives us an option of sharing the link to a question that we posted with other people we know, who we think might be able to answer the question. So, there is a possibility that the person who we send the link to will answer the question correctly. Ideally, we are supposed to accept the right answers.

So, a few questions like this might lead to a good amount of reputation change for those certain people. To me, it doesn't sound unethical. Because this is what is supposed to happen in the community that, you ask a question and somebody answers it correctly and you accept their answer.

But, according to the community rules, is this allowed? Is their a certain limit on accepting answers posted by some people or upvoting the answers? Does it in anyway count as a malpractice?

This question isn't specifically about Stack Overflow. It can be any site on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have already specified, that it doesn't seem ethical to me. If I get an answer that solves my problem, I am supposed to accept it. And about waiting, how long should I wait? Do you suggest that I don't accept such answers at all?

Comment: I already did. My comment was posted before Shadow answered

Comment: In my opinion the option for sharing sends out the wrong messages about how voting should be done. It leaves the way open for groups with vested interested or axes to grind to block vote, and almost seems to be endorsing this behaviour. This is not the way we should be assessing value to the coding community and it sends out the wrong message about Stack Exchange's values. Something which can poison a global community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity of the person answering your questions should not be relevant at all. You should upvote, downvote, or accept based on **content**, and content alone.

If the same person happens to answer lots of your answers, and their answers are good and solving your problems then yes, by all means, accept all of them. Nothing is wrong with this.

However, one thing to keep in mind: if that person is answering **only** your questions, and no other questions at all, and you accept only their answers, it can easily look suspicious and appear as if that person is actually a sock puppet account of yours, which is bad. In such a case, if you know that person outside SE, better contact them and ask them to take more active part on the site.

Comment: I get it. Thanks. Is there any clause relating to this, in the terms of use?